# Use an external (private) nuget server as upstream source in Azure Artifacts?

Tags: azure-artifacts

Is there any way of using an external private nuget feed (either an Artifact feed belonging to another organization, or a standalone private (basic auth) enabled nugetserver) as an upstream source in Azure Artifacts?

It is possible in other parts of Azure Devops as a service connection, but I can't find a way of either utilizing service connections nor specify a private external nuget as upstream source in Artifacts. The only options are public nuget servers and feeds present in Devops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. We're considering building support for custom upstream sources next quarter. This [Developer Community suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366068/custom-public-upstream-sources-in-nuget-package-ma.html) tracks the idea.